# Python multithreaded daemon (modules daemon and threading to use together )

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon, python-multithreading

I have a python daemon created with python-daemon [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)

My application works fine, but now I want to make it multithreaded.

The application was built from [this example](http://www.gavinj.net/2012/06/building-python-daemon-process.html) .

I understand how to use the module threading.

But how to use them both together?

I need to run a method `run()` of my application in different threads.
Aka

```
def run(self):
    # run threads.
    while True:
```

So only main thread does all daemon things like lock file etc. and other threads just do some extra work in parallel.

Is this possible? and how to do it?

Update. Maybe [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module is better then threading for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a python specific daemon package ? some tool exist to make any loop program into a daemon (start-stop-daemon comes to mind)

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          <whatever> 
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       <whatever> auto start.
### END INIT INFO

#set -x
set -e

if [ "$1" = "start" ]
    then
        start-stop-daemon --start --startas /usr/bin/python3 --pidfile /tmp/<whatever>.pid --make-pidfile --background --chdir '/var/local/<whatever>/' -- <whatever>.py

elif [ "$1" = "stop" ]
    then
        start-stop-daemon --stop --signal 2 --pidfile /tmp/<whatever>.pid
fi
```

else if you really need it, then i am afraid i do not understand your problem, you can simply start a thread like so

```
import threading
w = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(<args>, <args>, <args>))
w.setDaemon(True)
w.start()
#code
```

else if you want to run code in  a multiprocess way, you can do it like so

```
import multiprocessing
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(<args>, <args>, <args>))
p.start()
p.join()
#code
```